# Error: 0 - call to a member function find() on boolean

Tags: joomla-3.7

I am getting this Error when i visit my Homepage (http://www.volleyball-hammelburg.de/). When i refresh the Site a few times the Error is gone. But when i revisit the page after some time the error shows up again.
[image]

I think this happens since 3.7.0

Comment: This is way too broad. Try disabling your 3rd party modules and plugins 1 by 1 to see if the errors get rectified. If you find the extension causing the issue, try updating it to the latest version

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks Lodder. Was a misstake in one of my own modules. So no Joomla specific Error what i firstly thought.